# How to Connect Docker Logs to Sentry Service

Tags: docker, logging, sentry

Is there anyway exists that I connect `docker logs` to sentry service?

for example when a docker stopped due to some unexpected issues, I can see its logs in sentry web panel.

Comment: I do not know Sentry, but there is a list of [supported logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers), and Sentry is not present in it.

If Sentry supports [GELF](https://blog.docker.com/2017/02/adventures-in-gelf/), it may be possible to use the `gelf` driver. Otherwise, can you just use something like `syslog` and just let Sentry get logs from `syslog`?